# How can one avoid DatabaseObjectNotClosedException

Tags: android

How one we avoid this exception??

```
01-19 17:16:16.024: WARN/SQLiteCompiledSql(477): Releasing statement in a finalizer.    Please ensure that you explicitly call close() on your cursor: SELECT * FROM test

01-19 17:16:16.024: WARN/SQLiteCompiledSql(477): android.database.sqlite.DatabaseObjectNotClosedException: Application did not close the cursor or database object that was opened here

01-19 17:16:16.024: WARN/SQLiteCompiledSql(477): android.database.sqlite.DatabaseObjectNotClosedException: Application did not close the cursor or database object that was opened here

01-19 17:16:16.024: WARN/SQLiteCompiledSql(477):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:62)

01-19 17:16:16.024: WARN/SQLiteCompiledSql(477):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.(SQLiteProgram.java:80)

01-19 17:16:16.024: WARN/SQLiteCompiledSql(477):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.(SQLiteQuery.java:46)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this error appears because you didn’t close your database. Always close your sqlitehelper class

**EDITED:**

You have to implement like this in your class which is extending SQLiteOpenHelper class:

```
@Override
public synchronized void close() {
    if(db != null){
        db.close();
    super.close();
    }   
}
```

Comment: where i close the cursor..after all the db operations .or in the OnDestroy..pls help

Comment: db means: which object: means the object of SQLiteOpernHelper or the Helper class..Pls explain

Comment: db is youe SQLITEDatabse Object which is u r usinf in this class,it may differ name.i have used db.ok

Comment: Im using a helper calss EventDataSQLHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper  . Inside that im using only  onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)  and onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) methods.... I wrote another calss Test.java. insied that i intialize object of EventDataSQlHelper  and in the on create method i wrote Cursoe cr = getEvents() ;private Cursor getEvents(){
  SQLiteDatabase db = eventsData.getReadableDatabase();
     Cursor cursor = db.query(EventDataSQLHelper.TABLE,null, null,
      null, null, null, null);
     startManagingCursor(cursor);
     return cursor;
     }

Comment: db is name of SQLITEDatabase object name maybe you have specified another nam find it and replace the name of tht in my code

Comment: close cursor in onstop or on destroy event

Comment: i have done it.. still the exception is thrown when i navigate back from that activity where i made that cursor close

Comment: @chiragshah, please use a better English to write your answer / comments. It is not easy to read what you posted. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Well, as it says, call close() on your cursor!

Answer (score 1):

I was getting also that exception when i had a mistaken sql query when using the cursor. It might sound stupid but if somebody finds the same, it's another cause...

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the exception. I was calling

```
 db = eventsData.getReadableDatabase();
```

twice thats why the exception is thrown