# Android Database Update Record not working?

Tags: android, sqlite

I have created a database. And opened it :

```
public SQLiteDatabase open() {
String path = "/data/data/com.develop.assetcapture/databases/Asset_Directory";
db = SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(path, null);
return db;
}
```

I'm writing a user registration and what to enable them to reset their passwords.
I have no problem inserting new records or querying the database. However on my `resetPassword(username,password)` method I get an error message:

```
android.database.sqlite.DatabaseObjectNotClosedException: 
Application did not close the cursor or database object that was opened here
```

Please help, I've been stuck on this for too long now.

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4734886/how-can-one-avoid-databaseobjectnotclosedexception

Comment: you need to check before opening the database using `db.isOpen()` while you try to open it...if already open use that...But better way is to close the `db.close()` after querying the data..

Comment: public int checkUser(String CheckUserame) {
  SQLiteStatement query = db.compileStatement("SELECT count(*) FROM users WHERE username='" + CheckUserame + "'" );
  return (int) query.simpleQueryForLong();
 }... should I in other words hava closed it here somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

When you query the database you usually receive a Cursor object. Here is an example:

```
public Cursor querySomething() {
            final String whereClause = ...
            final String[] params = ...
    final Cursor c = this.getReadableDatabase().query(
            Table.TABLE_NAME,
            Table.allColumnNames(),
            whereClause,
            params,  // parameters for where clause
            null,   // group
            null,   // having
            null);  // order
    return c;
}
```

Using the cursor c you access the rows in the answer. When you have finished processing the answer you have to close the cursor object:

```
c.close();
```