# android.database.sqlite.DatabaseObjectNotClosedException: Application did not close the cursor or database object that was opened here

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

Here is my SQLiteHeler.java class.

```
//tables name in database
public static final String TABLE_NAME="Favtable";

//common column for all table
public static final String KEY_ID="id";
//column in alumnitable
public static final String KEY_CID="Courseid";
public static final String KEY_FavStatus="Status";

public SQLiteHelper(Context context) {

    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
}

//create tables
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database){

    String CREATE_NAME="CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "+TABLE_NAME+" ("+KEY_ID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"+KEY_CID+" VARCHAR, "+KEY_FavStatus+" VARCHAR)";
    database.execSQL(CREATE_NAME);
    database.close();

}
public void InsertData(int Courseid,int flag)
{
    Cursor cursor = null;
    SQLiteDatabase database = this.getReadableDatabase();
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    SQLiteQuery = "INSERT INTO FavTable (Courseid,Status) VALUES('" + Courseid + "', '" + flag + "');";
    database.execSQL(SQLiteQuery);
    database.close();
}
public void close() {
    if (database != null) {
        database.close();
    }
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase database, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    database.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+TABLE_NAME);

    onCreate(database);
}
```

}

What i am doing wrong?It giving error as

```
_android.database.sqlite.DatabaseObjectNotClosedException: Application did not close the cursor or database object that was opened here_
```

And i called create and insert methods of SQLiteHelper into my Fragment class by creating Object.

This is my CourseFragment.java.here i am calling onCreate and Insert Method

alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Yes",
                                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

```
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0,
                                                        int arg1) {
                                        flag = 1;


                                        /*s1="true";*/
                                        Courseid = mCourse.getCourseid();

                                        mCourse.setIsFavCourse(!mCourse.getIsFavCourse());
                                        mCourse.save();

                                        // Update listview
                                        mCourses.get(position).setIsFavCourse(
                                                mCourse.getIsFavCourse());
                                        courseListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                                //Add courseid and status to database
                                        favourite.onCreate(database);
                                        favourite.InsertData(Courseid,flag);

                                        // Start sync service for course
                                        Intent i = new Intent(context, MDroidService.class);

                                        i.putExtra("notifications", false);
                                        i.putExtra("siteid",
                                                session.getCurrentSiteId());
                                        i.putExtra("courseid",
                                                mCourse.getCourseid());

                                        context.startService(i);

                                    }
                                });
```

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4734886/how-can-one-avoid-databaseobjectnotclosedexception

Comment: `What i am doing wrong?` An awful lot of things. **1** - You are inserting your **integer** values as **strings**. **2** - You are creating a **useless** cursor, which is then moved to the first record (but it's not associated to any recordset) whe it's still **null**. **3** - And you never close it.

Comment: `Cursor cursor = null` and `cursor.moveToFirst` serve no purpose and the latter may cause issues. Not that these two lines would be causing the issue. if by saying _I called create_ you called `onCreate` that method is automatically called, so you shouldn't call it directly.

Comment: As suggested in above tutorial i called in my fragment activity as @Override
 public void onDestroy() {
  super.onDestroy();
  if (database  != null) {
   database.close();
  }
 }

Comment: I'd also suggest that rather than calling the the key column **id**, that you instead call it **_id**. If using a CursorAdapter (e.g. for Listviews), **_id** is required, so using **_id** can simplfy matters.

Comment: Oops missed the obvious. `this.getReadableDatabase();` should be `this.getWriteableDatabase();` in the **InsertData** method.

Comment: It may assist if you provided the relevant section of the log rather than just part of the message. Also it could assist if you also included the code that invokes/calls/uses the database. So, perhaps edit you question to include these.

Comment: @Mike sir,I have tried this.getReadableDatabase(); and removing Cursor statements.It was still not working.I edited my question.Please have look

Comment: @Rotwang sir,I am not getting where I am inserting values as string.While creating table i declared them as INTEGER.!!:-(

Comment: @Rotwang sir.Suggest me where and how to insert these values as Integers?

Comment: Don't use the **string** markers (`'`) around the values.

Comment: @Should i use this??                                                           SQLiteQuery = "INSERT INTO FavTable (Courseid,Status) VALUES(' + Courseid + ', '+ flag + ');";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After copying and running your code and then modifying it. The primary/initial issue is due to you closing the database when you create it in the **onCreate** method of the helper (**commented out in code below**).

However, as per the comments there are other issues, some of which the following code resolves. The following code works (as far as resolving the issue that you currently have) :-

```
public class SQLiteHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Courses";

    //tables name in database
    public static final String TABLE_NAME="Favtable";

    //common column for all table
    public static final String KEY_ID="_id";
    //column in alumnitable
    public static final String KEY_CID="Courseid";
    public static final String KEY_FavStatus="Status";

    public SQLiteHelper(Context context) {

        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
    }

    //create tables
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database){

        String CREATE_NAME="CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "+TABLE_NAME+" ("+KEY_ID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"+KEY_CID+" VARCHAR, "+KEY_FavStatus+" VARCHAR)";
        database.execSQL(CREATE_NAME);
        //database.close();

    }
    public void InsertData(int Courseid,int flag)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
        String SQLiteQuery = "INSERT INTO FavTable (Courseid,Status) VALUES('" + Courseid + "', '" + flag + "');";
        database.execSQL(SQLiteQuery);
    }


    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase database, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        database.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(database);
    }
}
```

Here's the code/calls I've used in the activity:-

```
    SQLiteHelper mydb = new SQLiteHelper(this);
    mydb.InsertData(0,10);
    mydb.close();
```

You should not have this line in your code (as posted after I answered) :-

`favourite.onCreate(database);`

Comment: Thank you @MikeT sir and Rotwang sir lot for correcting my mistakes.Thanks again.Boths help worked:-):-)Help means lot to me.Thanks agian.